# Cannot create a virtual environment for python by using node.js command line , terminal libraries from electron

Tags: python, node.js, electron, virtualenv

Im trying to create a graphical user interface using electron to create virtual environments for python

I tried out following libraries

```
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    exec('mkvirtualenv test_env_1', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          if(err){
            return err;
          }

          console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });


    var cmd = require('node-cmd');
    cmd.get(
      `
        mkvirtualenv test_env_2
      `,
      function(err, data, stderr){
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
```

Unfortunately none of the approaches created a virtual environment for python.

Tried `shelljs` node package as well,  and it says it does not support shell.exec for electron library.

How may I use nodejs to create a virtual environment for python?

Comment: Why do you use `mkvirtualenv` from [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper/)? Try `virtualenv` from [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/). *Unfortunately none of the approaches created a virtual environment for python.* Why do you think they dont work?

Comment: it can be any library the question is to execute those commands via nodejs because this is a part of a GUI software where it creates a virtualenvironment from a single button click and whats wrong of usinf mkvirtualenv ? @phd

Comment: `mkvirtualenv` is not a program — it's a shell function, to run it you have to source `virtualenvwrapper` into the current shell. Try `virtualenv` — it's a Python script.